# Forward slash key won't work on ABNT2 keyboard ( ThinkPad T450)

Tags: keyboard, redhat

I am using Linux RedHat on a ThinkPad T450 with an ABNT2 keyboard (Brazilian standard).

The problem is that the key which contains the forward slash and interrogation mark is not working. I have already tried every single input source available but none of them works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set to thinkpad60, it should work

```
sudo setxkbmap -model thinkpad60 -layout br
```